# How to set user agent in w3m

Tags: linux, browser, user-agent, agent, w3m

I'm using [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net). How do I go about overriding the user agent of this text based web browser? I have tried setting -header "User-Agent: blah" as an example, but I get the following error:

```
w3m: Can't load blah.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set the User-Agent by modifying the file `~/.w3m/config` and modifying the `user_agent` line. I have the following text and it seems to work as expected: `user_agent Mozilla/5.0 (Linux i686; U; w3m 0.5.3; en)`. That has no : or = signs in it, just so you get an idea of the syntax used.

This is with w3m version 0.5.3.

You can also set it with `w3m -header 'User-Agent: blah'` but the problem there is that it appears twice in the request. You can see the headers that w3m uses if you set up a netcat "webserver":

```
$ netcat -lp 9999
# then in another terminal:
$ w3m -header 'User-Agent: foo' http://localhost:9999
# back at netcat:
GET / HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: w3m/0.5.3
Accept: text/html, text/*;q=0.5, image/*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, bzip, bzip2, deflate
Accept-Language: en;q=1.0
Host: localhost:9999
User-Agent: foo
```

So it sends 2 User-Agent strings, which may not be parsed correctly by the real HTTP server.

Answer (score 3):

To update and clarify a few points from @richq's good answer:

- New w3m installs only create an empty config folder (~/.w3m)
- Having no ':' or '=' in the user agent string (UA) is irrelevant (w3m sends whatever is on that line)
- Confirmed that using the -header option to send a second UA is a bad idea (and unnecessary)
- A quick, one-liner to set the UA is:

  `echo 'user_agent <my-UA>' > ~/.w3m/config` (Paste desired UA over `<my-UA>`)
- And the much easier way to check the received UA is to simply grab one of the free UA site pages, Ex.

  `w3m whatsmyuseragent.com -dump` (Read UA on screen.)

Answer (score 1):

```
w3m whatsmyua.info -o user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Linux i686; U; w3m 0.5.3; en)'
```

or

```
echo -e '"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux i686; U; w3m 0.5.3; en)"\n"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux x86_64; U; w3m 0.5.3; en)"' >.ua

w3m whatsmyua.info -o user_agent="$(shuf -n1 .ua)"
```